# field name choice 'reference' is not a valid choice issue

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a view set in which i want to filter all of the records that have the same reference number. there is a reference model field in the Member model, but it is telling me that it is an invalid field.

this is the viewset:

```
from groups.models import Member
from ..serializers import MemberSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets

class MemberViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Member.objects.filter(field_name='reference')
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer
```

this is the models:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=22)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    open_tabs = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

this is the urls:

```
from groups.api.views.memberViews import MemberViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', MemberViewSet, base_name='member')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

so i want to filter out all of the member objects with the same reference field value...

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want your viewset to have only the `Members` who have a `reference` which is unique ?

Comment: yeah i want it to only show the members with the unique reference that is being passed into the url @ElioMaisonneuve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `Members` that have a specific `reference` in your viewset, you should override the `get_queryset` method and add the parameter to the url.

in the viewset :

```
from groups.models import Member
from ..serializers import MemberSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets

class MemberViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        reference = self.kwargs['reference']
        return Member.objects.filter(reference=reference)
```

and in urls :

```
from groups.api.views.memberViews import MemberViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'(?P<reference>[-\w]+)', MemberViewSet, base_name='member')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

see [the drf guide to filtering](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

Can you try using the following approach where `'SearchKey'` is the reference number you want to query against?

```
queryset = Member.objects.filter(reference__contains='SearchKey')
```

Comment: I tried but it did not work `queryset = Member.objects.filter(reference__contains='reference')`

Comment: Is there a row in your database where the field `reference` holds the value 'reference'?
That's what the current queryset is looking for.

Can you share a few actual values in the reference field, like say 'REFID1234'?


Then the query should be:

`queryset = Member.objects.filter(reference__contains='REFID1234')`